# Retract accidental edit

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I made an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6068970) where I accidentally removed all numbers from the question, not just the line numbers. My edit just got approved. Is there a way I can take it back? I left a comment on the question noting my mistake, but what else should I do to fix my mistake?

Comment: rollback, but I'm not sure if you can do that yet. click on the *edited x minutes ago* link and go to the revision that you want to rollback to, and click rollback... I did it for you

Comment: Or you can just edit the missing numbers back in. You can still see the revision history like cVplZ mentioned. OP approved your first edit so I guess he won't mind removing the line numbers. Also see here http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work