# Feature to remove my edit on other user question/answer before/after he reviews it

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits

**There should be feature in SO by which a user could remove his/her edit on some other users question before/after the original author reviews it.**

Today while editing [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35497722/tab-with-two-image-view-in-its-fragment) question, something happened. I was editing the question and before my edit was completed another user, named [*Cindy Meister*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3077495/cindy-meister), submitted his edit and it was peer reviewed and accepted.

After this I submitted my edit and my edits was also accepted. As I submitted the edit ofr review last my changes reflected on the question removing *Cindy Meister´s* changes.

Upon looking the edit history I noticed that changes made by *Cindy Meister* were thorough and they made the question more meaningful than changes made by me.
I thought I should revoke/remove my edits but I found that there is no option to do so.

After this I was forced to do the same changes which *Cindy Meister* did so as to make the question more meaningful.

So if Stack Overflow had an option to remove my edits either before peer reviews it or after, then it would be good.

I wrote this question because I was doing the same work which another user did and I got +2 reputation and my name below the question. I didn´t want that because the work was done by another user.

**Update:** here I am asking about rollback of my edits on another user's question.

Thanks, waiting for your suggestions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cancel edit before it gets approved](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/280891/cancel-edit-before-it-gets-approved), http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/302905/canceling-an-obsolete-edit, http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275229/retract-accidental-edit